# How to concatenate and subtract a StartTime from an EndTime while also converting it to HH:MM:SS (108)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to concatenate and subtract a StartTime from an EndTime while also converting it to `HH:MM:SS` ([style 108](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

```
SELECT      
     CONVERT(CHAR(8), StartTime, 108) +' - '+ CONVERT(CHAR(8), EndTime, 108)  AS "Time"
    , CONVERT(CHAR(20), Title) AS Title
    , CONVERT(CHAR(50), Description) AS Description
    , CONVERT(CHAR(20), StartTime - EndTime, 108) AS Length
```

I'm stuck here.

I only need the `HH:MM:SS` outputted to the "Length" which is the difference when subtracting `StartTime` from `EndTime`.

Running this doesn't subtract properly, but does hold the correct format from (style 108)

I need to Subtract THEN Convert, I feel like I've tried nearly everything and I'm just completely missing the logic.

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. I have removed the conflicting tags.

Comment: Why not convert to a `time` (assuming SQL Server)?

Comment: Yes SQL Server. And when I tried converting to time I was unable to apply the correct format in the output (HH:MM:SS).

Comment: Formatting is for the prrsentation layer, *not* the SQL layer.